# How do I delete only files created by the installer during update with install4j

Tags: install4j

I have a install4j project and want to make a project.

There is a `libs`-folder within my setup, where all my jars are packaged:

```
<install-dir>/libs/myA.jar
<install-dir>/libs/myB.jar
<install-dir>/libs/alien.jar
```

The alien.jar is a additional file, not created from my setup.
if I deliver a update with a packages `libs`-folder the `alien.jar` get deleted and I don't understand why.

There is a `DeleteFilesAction` before the `InstallFilesAction`, which has a filter that all `alien.jar` weon't be deleted. If I make a MessageBox after my `DeleteFilesAction`, the

> alien.jar

still exists.

When the InstallFileAction starts, the complete `libs`-Folder seems to be deleted.

I beleave there are configuration flags, which I don't know.

Question:
How do I delete the complete `libs`-folder, expect the `alien.jar`?

Comment: The installer does not delete any files unless you have an "Uninstall previous installation" action. And even that can only delete files that have been installed by a previous installer. The only way this file can be deleted by install4j is via a "Delete files or directories" action. Please check for more instances of that action in your project and disable all those actions to see if they are the problem.

Comment: OK, I found my Problem. I am deleting the libs directory with a DeleteFilesAction. Hoy can I delte all files in that folder but not the folder itself with that action? (I know I can simply delete it within Java, but I'd prefer the install4j - API because of the delayed deletion ad reboot-option.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible with an `DeleteFilesAndDirectory`-Action to delete all (unknown) files within a directory.

I used a Action where `<install-dir>/libs` is provided as folder to be deleted.
I provided a filter-Script for filenames (the alien.jar had a return value "false" the rest shozuld be deleted). But the action deletes the libs-dir as well. I think it works as designed, so it is not a bug.

For all peope with the same Problem a workarround or soultion:

```
com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.fileinst.FileInstaller fi = com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.fileinst.FileInstaller.getInstance();

File directory = new File(context.getInstallationDirectory(), "/libs");

File[] filesInLib = directory.listFiles();

for(File file:filesInLib){
   boolean shouldDelete= true;

   if(file.getName().toLowerCase().contains("alien")){
       Util.logInfo(null,"dexchange detected: " + file.getName());
       shouldDelete= false;
   }

   Util.logInfo(null,"Delete " + file.getAbsolutePath() + ": " +reval);

   if(shouldDelete){
      if (file.exists()) {
          Util.logInfo( null, "delete file: " + file);
          fi.deleteFile(file);
      }
   }
}

return false;
```

At Ingo Kegel:
Thanks for your help, I didn't want to open a support ticket, because I was quite sure it is no bug in you product. But I think another checkbox "delete if not empty" would help a lot in the `DeleteFilesOrDirectory` Action.